# Firestore - reducing amount of writes and reads by making changes locally, then pushing data to servers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a fair bit of work on a set of Firestore collections and documents. It amounts to a good amount of writes and reads, as I'm setting two-way refs and whatnot. **Multiple documents are being written to multiple times.**

Since Firestore offers offline capability, is it possible to reduce the number of writes via preparing all the data locally, then sending it to the server?

I'm using the Admin SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.  One document write is always going to cost one document write, no matter when or how that document was written.  [Batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) don't in any way reduce the number of documents written, they just make all the document writes take effect at the exact same moment in time.

If you're staging lots of changes to a single document to take effect later, then feel free to do that.  Just write the document whenever you've figured out what final document looks like, and no sooner.

Answer (score 1):

I'am moving away from google appengine standard Python 2.7 NDB to Svelte, Firestore and RxFire.

I was able to dramatically reduce the number of reads and writes by batching hundreds of appengine NDB entities (datastore / data objects) into a single document using a data object map.

Every data object has a batchId prop to optimize (batched) batch writes / document writes. (batchId = docId)

Most of the querying is now done in the client using filters. This resulted in very simple reactive Firestore queries using RxFire observables. This also dramatically reduced the number of composite indexes.

```
doc:
   batchId: docId
   map: data Objects
           batchId: docId
           other props ...
        ....
```

I also used maps of data objects for putting all kinds of configuration and definition data into single documents. This setup is easy to maintain and available with a single doc read. The doc reads are part of observables to react to doc changes.